# python update csv cells that meet criteria

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am setting up a scheduled scrape of a car sales website. I have a csv with previously scraped ads in the following format (most columns omitted for neatness):

```
id              year    first scan  last scan   active
OAG-AD-5459832  2005    31/01/2016  31/01/2016  Y
OAG-AD-12013782 2013    31/01/2016  31/01/2016  Y
OAG-AD-10487293 2015    31/01/2016  31/01/2016  Y
OAG-AD-12358252 1972    31/01/2016  31/01/2016  Y
AGC-AD-17247844 2015    31/01/2016  31/01/2016  Y
```

Each successive scrape currently returns a list of dicts, like so:

```
[{'body': u'\xa0Coupe','id': u'SSE-AD-3469148', 'odo': u'288', 'adtype': u'Private Seller Car'},
 {'body': u'\xa0Coupe', 'id': u'OAG-AD-12014474', 'odo': u'0', 'adtype': u'Dealer: Demo',}]
```

I have three cases I need to work on:

- a) If the scraped ad is not in the csv, append it to the end.
- b) If the
  scraped ad is in the csv and active = 'Y', update 'last scan' to
  today's date
- c) For any active = 'Y' ads in the csv that aren't in the
  list of scraped ads, change  active to 'N'

My current code for a) is below. I am not sure how to approach this to complete b) and c) efficiently, without copying new rows in for existing ads. Also - I am using pandas to open the csv file, not sure if I should keep using it for the manipulation or work with dicts.

```
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%y') #last scan date     
addb = pd.read_csv('pd output.csv') #csv of previously scraped ads
ids = addb['id'].tolist() 
addbdict = addb.to_dict(orient='records')

newads = []
for ad in adscrape:
    ad['last scan'] = date
    ad['active'] = 'Y'
    if ad['id'] not in ids:
        ad['first scan'] = date
        newads.append(ad)

addb2 = addb.append(newads)           
addb2.to_csv('pd output2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What is the matching characteristic: just the 'id'? Or do multiple fields all have to match?

Comment: Yep, just 'id' - the others don't need to match

Comment: You can use csvquerytool to run sql queries into your csv file. That will simplify things for you

Comment: I assume for newly added scaped ads, that first and last year are assigned `date`, and `active` should `Y` (judging from your code). But where does `year` come from? And what happens to the other fields such as `body`, `odo` and `adtype`? Are these the columns you left out in the CSV file for readability; or should they be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly how I would implement this, using Pandas functionality:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
adscrape = [{'body': u'\xa0Coupe','id': u'SSE-AD-3469148', 'odo': u'288', 'adtype': u'P\
rivate Seller Car'},
            {'body': u'\xa0Coupe', 'id': u'OAG-AD-12014474', 'odo': u'0', 'adtype': u'D\
ealer: Demo',}]

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y') #last scan date
addb = pd.read_csv('pd_output.csv') #csv of previously scraped ads
ids = addb['id'].tolist()
addbdict = addb.to_dict(orient='records')

newads = pd.DataFrame(adscrape)

existing = newads['id'].isin(addb['id'])
newads_to_be_appended = newads[~existing]
newads_to_be_appended['first scan'] = date
newads_to_be_appended['last scan'] = date
newads_to_be_appended['active'] = 'Y'
newads_to_be_appended['year'] = 999  # or something
addbplus = pd.concat([addb, newads_to_be_appended])

existing = addbplus['id'].isin(newads['id'])
addbplus.loc[existing,'last scan'] = date

addbplus.loc[~existing,'active'] = 'N'

addbplus.to_csv('pd_output.csv', index=False)
```

Note on the `existing` index variable: the first time, it is used to match scraped ads that are in the database (step a/). The second and third time, it's the other way around: it matches the database with scraped ads instead (steps b/ and c/). So feel free to rename the variable if it confuses you.

This being Pandas, there would probably be other ways.
I could, for example, imagine creating a large dataframe using an 'outer' join between `addb` and `newads`, and work from there.

Note: I'd avoid spaces in filenames. It works, but it is more likely to lead to errors at some point. Use an underscore (`pd_output.csv`, or a rather more appropriate name for such a database file) or a dash (hyphen) `-` to separate words.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simply iterating over new ads, adding them to your existing DataFrame work?
This kind of does all 3 in one pass:

```
addb['active'] = 'N'  # Set all ads to inactive
addb.set_index('id', inplace=True)
for ad in adscrape:
    fs = addb.loc[ad['id']]['first scan'] if ad['id'] in addb.index else date
    addb.loc[ad['id']] = pd.Series({'first scan': fs, 'last scan': date, 'active': 'Y'})
```

If `ad['id']` exists then it would update `last_scan` and `active`.
If `ad['id']` doesn't it exist it would create a new row (not sure where you are getting your `Year` info from, so it will be `NaN`